# Android NFC beam with tag writing

Tags: android, nfc

In Android, is it possible to enable both the Beam mode and Tag Writing for NFC simultaneously?
Which means after enabling both the Beam and Tag Writing,  I can tap either a phone or tag and it will beam/write to both.

I have tried a short sample and it doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure if it's not supported or is there something wrong with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic NFC comunication is only in target/initiator mode.

You will need to use NFC P2P, and even with it, I'm not sure that what you are looking for will works.

Try to get some informations about NFC P2P (hint, I think you will also need to get informations on LLCP and SNEP)

I hope this (bad) answer will help you.